# Find minimum values of both "columns" of list of lists

Tags: python, list

Given a list like the next one:

```
foo_list = [[1,8],[2,7],[3,6]]
```

I've found in questions like [Tuple pairs, finding minimum using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802128/tuple-pairs-finding-minimum-using-python) and
[minimum of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036913/minimum-of-list-of-lists) that the pair with the minimum value of a list of lists can be found using a generator like:

```
min(x for x in foo_list)
```

which returns

```
[1, 8]
```

But I was wondering if there is a similar way to return both minimum values of the "columns" of the list:

```
output = [1,6]
```

I know this can be achieved using numpy arrays:

```
output = np.min(np.array(foo_list), axis=0)
```

But I'm interested in finding such a way of doing so with generators (if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[min(l) for l in zip(*foo_list)]
```

returns [1, 6]

`zip(*foo_list)` gets the list transpose and then we find the minimum in both lists.
Thanks @mousetail for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `min()` for this. Like -

```
min1 = min(a for a, _ in foo_list)
min2 = min(b for _, b in foo_list)
print([min1, min2])
```

Will this do? But I think if you don't want to use third party library, you can just use plain old loop which will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about it, but I was wondering if this can be achieved in one line (I may be over-thinking it)